# Heroku проблема с БД

Tags: python, heroku, telegram, бот

Есть чат-бот для Телеграма, загружен на Heroku. Во время работы с чатом, предусмотрено создание простенькой базы данных с табличкой в 2 колонки. Вся проблема в том, что Heroku при выключении бота,  не сохраняет эти БД,и они слетают. Как можно победить этот момент? Использовать другой хостинг?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подключить **addon Postgres** и использовать эту базу

```
heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev
```

Узнать адрес базы можно этой командой

```
heroku config -s | grep HEROKU_POSTGRESQL
```

Comment: А, я понял, значит, придётся отказаться от sqlite