# Flask на heroku

Tags: flask, heroku, sqlalchemy

Такая проблема, написал блог на flask, в блоге используется 1 бд (sqlalchemy), закинул эту всю прелесть на heroku, потыкал, все работает как надо, создал пару постов, зарегал пару аккаунтов, сидел радовался. Зашел на следующий день, а БД откатилась на ту стадию, на которой она была при заливе на сервер (заливал не пустую БД). Т.е. база данных стала прежней.
Как сделать так, чтобы она не откатывалась и в чем вообще прикол откатов?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Heroku проблема с БД](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/690979/heroku-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%91%d0%94)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не читали [документацию](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted)? На Heroku файловая система временная. Платформа может в любой момент убить ваш инстанс, запустить несколько его копий или перекинуть его на другой сервак. Поэтому вы не сможете использовать SQLite.