# Heroku Telegram Bot - Cycling & Clearing

Tags: python, telegram-bot, heroku, aiogram

My bot works on Python, aiogram, sqlite. Im saving registered users into my database (1 table users.db file). Today my bot restarted and DB cleared. As i read later,

> Dynos are also restarted (cycled) at least once per day to help maintain the health of applications running on Heroku. Any changes to the local filesystem will be deleted. The cycling happens once every 24 hours (plus up to 216 random minutes, to prevent every dyno for an application from restarting at the same time)."

So my DB is cleared and my users need to register every day. Please give me an advice how can i solve my problem, may be another host or solution? Thanks

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/690979/heroku-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%91%d0%94

Comment: thanks dat works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, если в аддонах heroku подключить postgre. С SQLite такое не пройдет