# Heroku сбрасывает параметры

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, heroku, deploy

Здравствуйте уважаемые коллеги! У меня возникла проблема с Хироку. У меня есть телеграм бот на питоне. Он автоматом несколько раз в неделю ведет опрос в группе и записывает в json данные о участниках и о их ответах. Но я замечал несколько раз что бот сбрасывает данные. Будто обнуляется. Возвращается к тому состоянию в котором был задеплоин. Json оказывается пустой. Кто с таким сталкивался?

Comment: Думаю у вас в этом момент(перед обнулением) перезапускался бот

Comment: Возможно. Но как этого можно избежать? Что с этим делать?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/690979/heroku-проблема-с-БД?rq=1